# Clock Fanout Buffer Circuit

Tags: digital-logic, clock, buffer, fanout

I need a clock fanout buffer to drive 3 components with same clock, and I have found this reference design but could not understand the reason of using the inverter in the middle.

Can I directly connect the tcxo clock to fanout buffer?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square wave generator is running of 1.8V while the rest of the circuit is 3.3V.
The datasheet for the NB3N551 states that a high level clock input requires at least (VDD / 2) + 1V, which makes 2.65V, so it won't recognize the square wave generator's 1.8V output as logic high.
The Schmitt trigger inverter is acting as a level translator of sorts.

R8 and C16 form your classic Schmitt trigger inverter oscillator. When the output is high C16 charges and when the input trigger level is reached the output will go low and the same thing will happen in reverse.

The square wave generator's 1.8V output is capacitively fed into this to push the Schmitt trigger's input up and down so it oscillates in sync with the square wave generator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If i use a 3.3v clock generator(by using 3.3v regulator to tcxo's VDD), can i directly connect it to the buffer fanout.

Comment: Yes, that should work.